# How to calculate how many days have passed since the begging of the year, month, week?

Tags: python, date

I'm trying to calculate how many days have passed since the beginning of the year, month week, and I'm wondering what is the better way to approach this.

My code I have so far:

```
from_tx = params.get('from_tx', '')
    today = datetime.today()
    if from_tx == 'month':
        from_date = datetime(today.year, today.month, 1)
        days = str((today - from_date).days)
    elif from_tx == 'week':
        from_date = timedelta(days=datetime.today().weekday() % 7)
        days = str(from_date.days)
    elif from_tx == 'year':
       .....
    params['from_tx'] = days
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int(today.strftime("%j").lstrip("0"))` should give you the day of the year

`today.day` is the number of days since the begining of the month

and `today.strftime("%w")` or `today.weekday()` will give you days since begining of week